# If there is a $T$ such that $V(t)<V(t-T) \ \forall t$, does that imply $V(t) \to 0$?

Tags: limits, functions, inequality

Let $V(t)$ denote a continuous scalar function $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Assume that we can find a constant $T \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $V(t)<V(t-T)$ for all $t$. Does that imply that $V(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Any strictly decreasing function would satisfy your condition for any $T>0$.

Comment: indeed, but the class of functions that satisfy the mentioned condition includes much more functions than strictly decreasing functions.

Comment: So, one can then find a function, $V$, which satisfies the condition, but such that $V(t)$ does not converge to $0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ (for example, $v(t)=-t$).

Comment: Thank you, yes that is a counter example. what can be said if we constrain $V$ such that $V(t)>0 \ \forall t$?

Answer (score 1):

No, pick any number $a \in \mathbb R$ and let $V(t) = e^{-t} + a$.  This function is monotonically decreasing so for all $t$ we have $V(t) < V(t - 1)$ but $V(t) \to a$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Let me reformulate the question. If the original conditions are true, does that imply that the function converges to something, not necessarily 0?

Comment: No, take V(t) = -t, this is again monotonically decreasing but it does not converge.

Comment: and if $V$ is bounded below, e.g. $V(t)>0 \forall t$?

Comment: I believe it still doesn't have to be the case that $V(t)$ converges as $t \to \infty$ but the counterexamples become harder to describe with non-obvious details to check.

Comment: To me it seems that it actually should imply that it converges, but I need a proof. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: It implies that for any $a$ the sequence $V(a + nT)$ converges as $n \to \infty$, but it doesn't imply that $V(t)$ does.  The easiest counterexample I can think is this.  For each integer $n$ define $V(n) = 0$ and $V(n + 1/2) = e^{-n} + 1$.  Define $V$ for the remaining values of $t$ by linear interpolation (connect those points on the graph with lines).  This satisfies your condition for $T = 1$ and $V(n) \to 0$ and $V(n + 1/2) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ so $V(t)$ does not converge as $t \to \infty$.